# Python Helmert Transformation parameter and residual handling

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates

I'm looking for some starting points to implement an algorithm to calculate Helmert Transformation parameters (4- and/or 7-parameter). I found already some basic implementation e.g. https://github.com/rstulug/Helmert_transformation. Currently I'm not quite sure how to deal with remaining errors after the least square fit.

Comment: Maybe related: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Calculating-towgs84-values-from-source-dest-xyz-file-td5335643.html

Comment: Yes close, sad that the suggested program (http://helmparms3d.sourceforge.net/) shows no source code :P.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the source code from helmparms3d. Well maybe it helps me a little bit. But my question regarding the handling of the residuals is still open.

Comment: You can regard the remaining error as the "accuracy of the transformation".